# Should the tag [vhdl-generate] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The tag vhdl-generate currently has [9 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl-generate) under it. It's just a sub topic tag of VHDL. The separate tag kinda made sense when the feature was first introduced in 2006. The feature is part of the IEEE 1076-2008 standard which has gain user and vendor adoptions over older versions of VHDL. At this point the vhdl-generate tag does not add much and is rarely uses.

Should the vhdl-generate tag be removed and only have a vhdl tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the tag from those questions and voted to close one of them.

At 03:00 UTC the tag should be gone when the magic script has run and no new questions are tagged with it.